# Get total length of div tag using CSS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this `<div>` container:

```
div#container {    
    width: 600px;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    margin: 20px 10px 40px 10px;
}
```

I need help finding out the total length of this `<div>` container.

Comment: Yes, using javascript

Comment: Check out the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get its height.

```
var height = $("#container").get(0).getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/571803oh/)

Comment: any chance i might get help with the following? (so i won't start another question)   Add Red colour for the first elemnt of a list and green colour to the last element of the same list in CSS

Comment: @kopki of course you have to ask another one question with your new problem. Because that will be spotted by other experts too. And your new question may help others in future. :)